# Deploying someone else's Laravel project (mysql connection issue)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm new to this business. I use ubuntu and homestead, downloaded the project and dump dump, there was no env configuration file in the folder., I took env from a clean project and entered my settings, then I ran vagrant up, vagrant ssh, went into the project folder and tried to simply execute php artisan as a result, I get this kind of message:

> "In Connection.php line 664:
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'xxxx_db.newsletter_settings' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `newsletter_settings` limit 1)"

where "xxxx_db" is the database that I entered into env, and "newsletter_settings" is taken as I understood from app / Eloquent / NewsletterSettings

from the lines:

```
class NewsletterSetting extends Model

{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'newsletter_settings';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    /**
```

My dear connoisseurs question: how can I tie up the project correctly?
I tried to comment out and temporarily delete the file from which the protected $ table = 'newsletter_settings' is taken;
but nothing worked.

For earlier I apologize for my english

Comment: Have you cleared the cache (php artisan config:cache) after introducing changes in the .env file?

Comment: Did you run the migrations?

Answer (score 1):

Create Database

change db name as below

DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

DB_PORT=3306

DB_DATABASE=yourdbname

DB_USERNAME=root

DB_PASSWORD=

Run command php artisan migrate

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** *Artisan Cached Config Files*

Try to run `php artisan optimize:clear`, this will clear all of your cached config files and mean any changes you make to your config files will take effect immediately.

---

**Step 2** *Manual Cached Config Files*

If you cannot even run `php artisan` to clear the cache, you can delete them manually by removing the files within `bootstrap/cache`. (Keep the git ignore)

---

**Step 3** *Code Review*

If the cache has no effect, then it may be that you have database calls somewhere within a  `boot` method on one of your classes. The `boot` methods all run before the content of `php artisan` would have returned. It is not uncommon for developers who don't frequently delete their databases to fall into this trap as it won't manifest itself until someone tries to install the project from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create Database

2.set database name and credentials in .env

3.Run command `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, found in a separate Kernel.php this kind of string:

```
    $setting = NewsletterSetting::first();
    if(!empty($setting)) {
        $schedule->command('command:newsletter')
            ->withoutOverlapping()
            ->days($setting['weekdays'])
            ->at($setting->send_time);
    }
```